# deploy flask application on ubuntu/apache2: virtual host configuration

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu, flask

I'm trying to deploy a python/flask application on an apache2 installation on ubuntu (14.04), following the instructions at the [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps)

The application seems to work and if I point the browser to `http://mywebsite.com/` I correctly see the message returned by the Flask application.

My problem is, what if I want to install a second site as a different virtual host on the same machine (say a non-python application)?
What I would like is that the virtual host is mapped to an URL like `http://mywebsite.com/FlaskApp`, while having the possibility to define another virtual host at `http://mywebsite.com/MyOtherWebApp`

This is the FlaskApp.conf file as per instructions on the mentioned article:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName mywebsite.com
            ServerAdmin admin@mywebsite.com
            WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
            <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
            Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
            <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            LogLevel warn
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and here is how the `/var/www` folder is structured after I installed the python app

```
/var/www
    +-- FlaskApp
    ¦   +-- FlaskApp
    ¦   ¦   +-- flaskenv
    ¦   ¦   +-- __init__.py
    ¦   ¦   +-- __init__.pyc
    ¦   ¦   +-- static
    ¦   ¦   +-- templates
    ¦   +-- flaskapp.wsgi
    ¦
    +-- MyOtherWebApp
        +-- ...
```

Some notes with more details:

1. I don't have the possibility to use different domain names or diffent ports for the different VirtualHost
2. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660070/apache-multiple-virtual-hosts-on-the-same-same-ipdiffrent-urls) thread suggesting to use the directive `ServerAlias` as shown below to solve a similar problem, but if I do this and go to `http://mywebsite.com/` I see a directory listing of the FlaskApp folder instead of the results of the flask service invocation, as in the screenshot below:

here the changed FlaskApp.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mywebsite.com/FlaskApp
    ServerAlias mywebsite.com/FlaskApp
    .
    .
    .
```

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: hmms ! You try using wsgi document as cgi ? am i right ? Check directory definition for `FallbackResource, DirectoryIndex,IfModule dir_module` and remove `initial startup proccess on flask`. Directory index your starting point, can define on main `apache2.conf`(But don't forget directory pattern, so not all, only your script directory).

Comment: I'm afraid I don't fully understand what you mean: I just got the virtual host configuration from the linked article (and as I mention, everything works fine if I'm satisfied having the application respond to the URL `http://mywebsite.com`).

Answer (score 2):

I think you missed that url in your controller. Perhaps you can add a index.html in FlaskApp folder to redirect to the correct url (or the other way around, if you leave ServerName mywebsite.com/FlaskApp, put an index file to redirect to FlaskApp).
If index.html "hack" doesn't suit your needs, you may add another virtualserver to redirect from / to /FlaskApp/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but my problem is exactly how to configure the virtual server to map to `http://mywebsite.com/FlaskApp/` URL (since the solution I found in the mentioned thread doesn't seem to work). I'd prefer not to have to make changes to the flask application (which I took from the linked article example, and basically works as expected if I just directly map the apache virtual server to the main domain name mywebsite.com)

Comment: Apache Virtual server configuration uses a hostname to show a website or another, so you should use the domain only under virtual server config. The url rewrite you need (redirection to /FlaskApp) could be done by adding:
  Redirect "/" "/FlaskApp"

Comment: I tried to add the `Redirect` but without success. In any case I finally solved using a subdomain `ServerName flaskapp.mywebsite.com`.

Comment: Create a conf  `sub_domain.main_domain.com`  add to site apache ! **Huh , can't publish two service on single port !**  So read my comment, apache redirect using system resource 2 time. Use  flask app as `CGI` or remove `APACHE` only use `FLASK`. `I love your worries` :) @chrx