# Deploying Flask App on Digital Ocean (apache2)

Tags: apache, flask, server, apache2, digital-ocean

I have seen this tutorial using nginx
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-22-04
And this old tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps

I have no issue deploying a Flask app to http://[IP address]:5000. However it doesn't seem to be applying it to the domain name. What is the missing step? I know very little about servers so appreciate the help! Thanks!

Additionally I don't want it to be deployed directly on domain.com. I would like it to appear on domain.com/FlaskApp. I have seen this related question: [deploy flask application on ubuntu/apache2: virtual host configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38572059/deploy-flask-application-on-ubuntu-apache2-virtual-host-configuration)